# GCP 2nd generation Cloud Functions: How can I use Secrets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

**How can I use a secret when creating a 2nd gen Cloud Function?**

When I create a 1st generation Cloud Function, I can add secrets like so:

[image: Cloud Function 1st gen has option adding secret]

However this option is not available when creating a 2nd generation Cloud Function:

[image: Cloud Function 2nd gen no option adding secret]

Comment: I cannot see the option in UI but may be achievable using [`gcloud beta functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy)

Answer (score 2):

When you create a 2nd generation Cloud Function, you actually create a Cloud Run.

So after the creation of your function go to Cloud Run, find the function you created, click on Edit & Deploy new revision and then add the references to the secret you need:

[image: Edit and Deploy Cloud Run Secrets]